# IPAD Change APP Folder after Update

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova

My Cordova/IPAD application download files to:

cdvfile://localhost/persistent

And i save the entry.toURL() value using WebSQL.

But when i send a new version of app using TestFlight and install it, all links (entry.toURL()) change.

The var/mobile/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXX changes.

Why this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, if reinstall ( remove and add ) app the unique folder is created again!